# using jsTree with MVC .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an MVC project and im trying to call a method in the controllers object but the method isnt being called, here is the code.

### .NET

```
Namespace WindowTreeView
Public Class DefaultController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /Default

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function


    Function GetTreeNodes() As JsonResult



    End Function


End Class
End Namespace
```

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#divJsTreeDemo").tree({
    data: {
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Default/GetTreeNodes",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : "{}"
    }
});
});
```

Comment: url seems wrong. try this.  url: "/Default/GetTreeNodes",

Comment: In your data, change `method: "POST"` to be `type: "POST"`

Comment: @Priyank Patel, thanks for replying, but that didnt work but ill use this url from now on.

Comment: have you define the path in global.asax?

Comment: @mazhar kaunain baig, no i havent is this a must because the articles i have read do not mention this

Comment: @mattytommo, it looks like this helped as the jsTree is now looking into the js file but im getting a bug in the vakata.js file saying object is not supported at this point "vakata_context.element"

Comment: Error is here vakata_context.element
   .delegate("li", "mouseenter", function (e) {

Comment: What's the vakata.js file? Can you post that?

Comment: Or just post that actual function you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're requesting data, try a GET request - not post!

```
method: "POST"
```

Then you can return your JSON result and parse in js.

Answer (score 0):

I basically copied this from their site (have a look at the [last sample](http://www.jstree.com/demo) (PHP & mySQL demo + event order)), and got it up and running. Modified the pasted sample a bit.

```
   $(function () {
        $("#demo")
            .jstree({
                "plugins": ["..."],
                "json_data": {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": '@Url.Action("GetChildren")',
                        "data": function (n) {
                            return {
                                "id": n.attr ? n.attr("id") : -1
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },  
            });
    }
```

But isnt this your problem perhaps... $("#divJsTreeDemo")**.tree**({